# BadParcelableException on passing TurnBasedMatch in intent

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm developing a game with turn based multiplayer support. To fetch a list of the current games of a player I use the `GamesClient.loadTurnBasedMatches` method. This works fine but when I try to open a new activity and pass a match to it crashed. The code I use to launch the new activity is

```
    private void openMatch(TurnBasedMatch match) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MultiPlayerGame.class);
    intent.putExtra("match", match);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

But after executing this code I get this error: (It is limited like this so I can't see the entire package name)

> 02-03 21:28:02.880: E/AndroidRuntime(5513): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackage.MultiPlayerGame}: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.turnbased.a

The line where it actually crashes is:

```
match = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("match");
```

Now I'm not sure if this is a fault of mine or is there a bug somewhere in the play-services-lib. Or is it related to proguard? Btw, if I use the built in intent to show the user his games the same method works. (in onActivityResult)

```
if (request == RC_LOOK_AT_MATCHES) {
    TurnBasedMatch match = data.getParcelableExtra(GamesClient.EXTRA_TURN_BASED_MATCH);
if (match != null)
  openMatch(match);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around it by only sending the matchId to the next activity. In that activity I use `GamesClient.getTurnBasedMatch`. It might be that the default intent does this in the backgroud but I'm not sure.

Comment: How do you get the match Id from a TurnBasedMatchConfig object?

Answer (score 0):

Your `TurnBasedMatch` must implement Parcelable contract. See [examples here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/03/example-to-implement-parcelable.html) or [here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-parcelable-example-passing-data-between-activities/)

Comment: TurnBasedMatch is a class from the play-services library and implements Parcelable (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatch.html)

Comment: Are you using proguard?

Comment: According to my project.properties I'm not

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
intent.putExtra("match", new TurnBasedMatchEntity(match));
```

TurnBasedMatchEntity is a class that implements TurnBasedMatch and supports being sent as a Parcelable. You can retrieve it the same way as before.

```
TurnBasedMatch match = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("match");
```

Answer (score 0):

[`TurnBasedMatch`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatch) (and all of its implementations) implement `Freezable<>`, which has a [`freeze()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/data/Freezable.html#freeze()) method.  Calling it will get you an instance that's suitable for serialization.

I suspect (but haven't confirmed) that the call to `freeze()` simply returns a [`TurnBasedMatchEntity`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatchEntity) object.  The nice thing about this solution is you don't have to care; all you have to care about is what's defined in the interface.

As a side note, the `TurnBasedMatch` interface extends [`Parcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html), which *should* mean every implementation is also parcelable... but it appears `TurnBasedMatchRef` doesn't actually implement it (hence the exception). Implementations shouldn't violate their interfaces like this, but that appears to be how it is.